# Unexplained DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, hosting, web-hosting

I have a website hosted on http://app.mytender.io. It works half the time, but the other time I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

The DNS entries are done in the hosted zone of AWS, and all looks correct. How can I best trouble shoot it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Interestingly the site works fine with the alias (chat.spark-ai.co.uk), which was registered on a different site. It also works fine when I access the site directly over its IP address http://44.208.84.199/.

This is the vhost.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mytender.io
    ServerAlias chat.spark-ai.co.uk 
    DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/www
    ServerAdmin info@spark-ai.co.uk
    <Directory /home/ec2-user/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Those are the entries in the hosted zone:
[image]

Comment: are yo usure about using http instead https nowadays?

Comment: will change that once I have it all working.

Comment: Please tell us the domain of it. Without knowledge of how things are configured, it's difficult to do fault finding.

Comment: In the background is a domain rewirte that is happening ? (ie; mysite.com >> app.mytender.io/mysite)

Comment: added additional info

Answer (score 0):

Your domain registrar is in error. The information published/propagated don't fit your screen.

Your NS listing that you shared dont fit the public's one my computer retrieve;

The NS I see from my side, watch the wixdns's one.

```
ns-1234.awsdns-26.org
ns-438.awsdns-54.com
ns0.wixdns.net
ns1.wixdns.net
```

The ns0.wixdns.net return me non-existant for app.mytender.io

[image]

If you compare to one of your AWS NS which work:

[image]

Comment: We are hosting the www. website on wix. I assume this is causing the issue? Can it be configured on wix so it only listens to the www but not to the app subdomain?

Comment: @Nickpick Wix probably had the domain and kept it nameserver attached to it by error, while you modified the public zone on AWS. If you have access to wix NS via an admin panel, it would be to add app.mytender.io there too to fix the error in the short term, but IMO it's simplier to just use one NS service, and point www to wix directly.

Comment: @Nickpick To note it, the fact you have 2 AWS and 2 wix NS, make it logical too in a round-robin scenario that 1 query on 2 were failing. (as app.mytender.io is unknown to wix)

Comment: I only think about a crossover ND delegation for the subdomain, but I am unaware if this might work the way I think in my head